# How to mix the audio files and upload to the server

Tags: core-audio, audiokit, avassetexportsession

I am using AudioKit in my project. By using the process suggested in the [mixing nodes playground example](https://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Basics/Mixing%20Nodes/), I am playing the multiple audios. My requirement is to upload the mixed audio to the server and displayed and played some other screens. I followed this suggestion. [How to get and save the mixed of multiple audios in to single audio in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816376/how-to-get-and-save-the-mixed-of-multiple-audios-in-to-single-audio-in-swift) but it's not working.

Give suggestions to get the mixed audio output for uploading to the server.

Answer (score 1):

AudioKit provides a node recorder that can be attached to any node in your signal chain (though it seems to prefer being connected to mixer nodes).

First set up a place for the recording to be kept:

```
let file = try AKAudioFile()
```

Then assign a recorder to record to that file

```
let recorder = try AKNodeRecorder(node: nodeYouWantToRecord, file: file)
```

Start recording:

```
try recorder.record()
```

Stop recording at a later time:

```
recorder.stop()
```

Then save your file:

```
file.exportAsynchronously(name: "nameString",
                          baseDir: .documents,
                          exportFormat: .caf) { [weak self] _, _ in
          // optional do something after exporting
        }
```

Check out how this playground saves the AudioKit output: https://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Basics/Mixing%20Nodes/

Comment: Hi @Aurelius Prochazka,

Comment: I want the Mixer output(multiple audios playing at a time output ) as an audio file from the above link. Give suggestions to get that Mixer output as a single audio file to save in local directory.

Comment: @Aure i'm new to AudioKit is there anyway to take multiple files add them to a mixer and export that mixer without having to go through realtime recording?